# How to communicate between angular and spring with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I am trying to get my Spring Boot, Angular and Mysql together making use of docker-compose (locally it is working). Spring Boot Image as well as angular image are working correctly after executing docker-compose up. I can see my angular app in the browser and I can make successfull Rest Call to my Spring API. The main problem ist, that if I make a Request from Angular  to the API there is no successful Rest Call anymore...
Problem could be with db... first it says:

`/usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

in the console. But a bit later as last console output for db it says:

`mbind: Operation not permitted`

I don't know if this is a problem because I can make some Restcalls from browser (not angular) successfully as written earlier.

Another assumption I have is, that ports have to be configured in another way.. but I tried already a lot of different combinations also with spring application + always creating new spring image.

What can also be an issue is, that the db throws some SQL errors like

`` Error executing DDL "alter table userrole add constraint userIdReference foreign key (`user_id`) references `user` (`user_id`)" via JDBC Statement ``

But still I can make some RestCalls.. and for instance within MySql workbench I can import the sql file without any problems and start spring boot + angular locally to successfully start the project.

`springpart_1   | Hibernate: select * from product where product.current_name = ?`

Messages like above do appear on console after starting docker compose-up but does not load anything into angular client.

`GET http://localhost:8077/products net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Other than that I have no real clue what could be the problem.. probably also because I am new to docker. Thank you in advance for your help.

**docker-compose_file**

```
services:
  springpart:
    image: ce153fc5b589
    ports:
      - '8077:8077'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306:3306
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
    - .src/main/resources/guitarshop/currentGuitarshopData:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=guitarshop
    networks:
      - backend
  angularpart:
    image: b8140c7fedec
    ports:
    - '4200:80'
    networks:
      - frontend
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

**angular-image-creation docker_file**

```
FROM node:alpine As builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/guitarShopAngular/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

**application.properties_file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/guitarshop?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = mypassword
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
server.port = 8077
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500KB
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=false
```

If you need any more information just let me know..

Comment: Hi, what version of the mysql jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: Yes that looks fine.  Could you post your application.properties?

Comment: The only thing that looks a bit strange in your compose file is this "DATABASE_PORT=3306:3306" which I would expect to be something like this "DATABASE_PORT=3306".

Comment: If you "docker container exec ..." into the springapp container, can you curl "http://localhost:8077/products"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your volume bind mount like so:
"./src/main/resources/guitarshop/currentGuitarshopData:/var/lib/mysql"

Like mentioned in the comments I had no issues with getting the app up and running.  In terms of the data it seems like the db files included in the project don't have any data, but I was able to add data manually and then see that data through the app.  The only real issue in your compose was the bind mount path, but once I fixed that the data I added persisted after recreating containers.

Here are some suggestions as ideally you should be able to clone the repo and run "docker-compose up -d" and have the app running.  Right now that isn't possible since you first have to build your spring app locally, then manually build the spring and angular docker images, then run compose up.

1. Create a new root folder and move the backend and frontend folders into it.
2. Move the compose file to the root folder.
3. Look into building your spring app by using a multi stage build like explained here: https://spring.io/blog/2018/11/08/spring-boot-in-a-container/#multi-stage-build.
4. Modify your compose file to something like this:

"

```
version: '3'
services:
  springpart:
    build: ./GuitarShopBackend
    ports:
      - '8077:8077'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
  db:
    image: 'mysql:8.0.17'
    volumes:
      # This will initialize your database if it doesn't already exist with your provided sql file
      - ./GuitarShopBackend/src/main/resources/guitarshop/initialGuitarshopData:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      # This will persist your database across container restarts
      - ./GuitarShopBackend/src/main/resources/guitarshop/currentGuitarshopData:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=guitarshop
    networks:
      - backend
  angularpart:
    build: ./GuitarShopAngular
    ports:
      - '4200:80'
    networks:
      - frontend
networks:
  frontend: null
  backend: null
```

Comment: Yes, if you have the project on github that I can clone and test locally that would be very helpful.

Comment: From what I can see everything seems fine.  I would change the folder structure so that you have a root folder which contains your docker-compose file and the backend and frontend folders, but that really isn't causing any issues.

Comment: I don't see any data in your mysql db that is being bind mounted (I was able to connect using mysql workbench), but as far as the springboot app it seems to be working ok.

Comment: I improved the project structure according to @Carlos. You can run the project now with a single docker-compose up in order to save time. [Here](https://github.com/pr0gr4mm4r/guitarShopBundle) is the new github link. Further I wonder, which kind of data you (@Carlos) could add to the application (product or user) and how? The main issue is still not fixed. So the data from sql file, which actually contains a lot of ddl statements is still not visible in angular frontend.

Comment: Hi @david-raub, I used MySQL Workbench to insert some test data and was able to see that via the angular app.  That being said I totally missed the sql file in the data directory, so in that case you need to change your bind mount similar to what you originally had see updated answer.

Comment: Make sure you move your sql file into a new directory named "initialGuitarshopData".